# Integrating video.js with Angular7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, video-streaming, video.js

I want to use videojs to render a HLS stream on my webpage.Stream is working well on vlc while on browser using videojs it plays the stream but doesnt seem to load completely.All implicit features of videojs player appear in raw HTML form.
Below is the screenshot of how it shows just below the playing video.
I could have posted the code snippets but i dont know which file should I post.I thought someone could guess where the problem is occurring.Please help I am frustrated by this.[image]

Comment: Can u create stackblitz example

Comment: You haven't included Video.js's CSS

Comment: @Cagri  actually it is working very well on stackblitz in built browser.For some reason stackblitz is not saving my work.But I am sure that it is same code as on localhost machine.

Comment: @misterben I am very sure I did that right. Can it be some cors issue.